# With a umask value of 457 it should come as w, x, - 210 (666-457) but instead i am seeing it as w,w,-..(220). why is that?

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, umask

[you can find the snapshot of the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOnDM.png)

With a umask value of 457 it should come as w, x, - 210 (666-457) but instead i am seeing it as w,w,-..(220). why is that?

Comment: please update your question to give some context on the issue you are experiencing and give some more details - also can you add the error message to the question often external links expire in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break this down:
umask does not do substraction, but rather a bitwise operation. It works by switching off the bits in the premission that are set on the umask, so in this case:

```
6: 110 4:100 -> 010 ->2
6: 110 1:101 -> 010 ->2
6: 110 7:111 -> 000 ->0
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you . Yes to an extent. But in the second bit. 6: 110 and 5: 101.. shouldnt it be 011 ?

Comment: As I said, umask switches off the bits on the position, so in the case of 6 and 5: bit one in umaks is cheseck, it's set -> result bit will be zero. Bit two in umask is checked, ist's zero, so bit two is unhanged, so it'1. Then bit 3 of umask is checekd, it's one, so the result bit is zero.

Comment: You can't set an umask for a directory, but where it's supported you can use `setfacl` to set up default premissions.https://askubuntu.com/questions/44534/how-to-set-umask-for-a-specific-folder